# Having problems getting vue-i18n to work with nuxt generate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internationalization, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I'm building a small Nuxt project from scratch as a learning exercise. Everything works as intended when I use the local server but my language switcher isn't updating any of the translation fields when I use nuxt generate.

From what I can tell troubleshooting the static site, vue-i18n is correctly populating the textfields with the default translation, it's including all of the translation locales in the deployed code, and my language switcher is changing the window.$nuxt.$i18n.locale property. I think I'm probably misunderstanding something and using it incorrectly but google hasn't been able to solve this for me.

(I'm using vue-i18n instead of nuxt-i18n because these were the requirements on an old job interview test and I'm reusing my code for a portfolio piece.)

Source code: https://github.com/spacecowgoesmoo/Nuxt-Portfolio-Samples/tree/master/i18nArticle

Deployed site: https://www.taylorcalderone.com/frontendPortfolio/subpages/i18nArticle/

Answer (score 1):

install vue-i18n by command:

```
npm install vue-i18n
```

add plugin to nuxt.config.js

```
plugins: ['~/plugins/i18n.js']
```

plugins/i18n.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'

Vue.use(VueI18n)

export default ({ app, store }) => {

  app.i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: store.state.locale,
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
    messages: {
      'en': require('~/locales/en.json'),
      'fr': require('~/locales/fr.json')
   }
  })

  app.i18n.path = (link) => {
    if (app.i18n.locale === app.i18n.fallbackLocale) {
      return `/${link}`
    }

    return `/${app.i18n.locale}/${link}`
  }
}
```

add to store index.js

```
export const state = () => ({
  locales: ['en', 'fr'],
  locale: 'en'
})

export const mutations = {
  SET_LANG (state, locale) {
    if (state.locales.includes(locale)) {
      state.locale = locale
    }
  }
}
```

locals/en.json

```
{
  "links": {
    "home": "Home",
    "about": "About",
    "english": "English version",
    "french": "French version"
 },
  "home": {
    "title": "Welcome",
    "introduction": "This is an introduction in English."
  },
  "about": {
    "title": "About",
    "introduction": "This page is made to give you more informations."
  }
}
```

locals/fr.json

```
{
  "links": {
    "home": "Accueil",
    "about": "À propos",
    "english": "Version Anglaise",
    "french": "Version Française"
  },
  "home": {
    "title": "Bienvenue",
    "introduction": "Ceci est un texte d'introduction en Français."
  },
  "about": {
    "title": "À propos",
    "introduction": "Cette page est faite pour vous donner plus d'informations."
  }
}
```

now you are use i18n index.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="Content">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="Content__Title">
        {{ $t('home.title') }}
      </h1>
      <p>{{ $t('home.introduction') }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

For me, this issue with the generate command was due to the fact I was using `v-if` on the `<nuxt>` component.

---

Hossein's answer is simply a copy of https://nuxtjs.org/examples/i18n/ which I recommend you revisit.

OP I think you're missing the middleware. And you shouldn't be using window.location but nuxt-links like `<nuxt-link :to="$i18n.path('about')">Home</nuxt-link>` or in method form for your dropdown like this:

```
handleSelect(path) {
      this.$router.push({
        path: this.$i18n.path(path)
      });
    }
```

That works for me anyway.

I've copied the Nuxt official example to the letter and everything seems to be working with the exception of capturing page title and meta description with `nuxt generate`.

Any insights would be appreciated.